# Sinch VoIP call lagging and voice data are not in real time

Tags: android, sinch

I have created VoIP app using **android programming** and **sinch services** but I am facing two major problem :

1. When I call user it try to initiate a call with user number but the call get ended after waiting and then in other number I am getting ***callscreen*** activity even the calling person's callscreen is finished and **Timeout**. **Possible cause : Delay in voice data**.
2. After call being established I can bearly hear other person. It's like some broken voice data or voice packets are not completely received at other end. Again I am facing the problem ***1*** here if I am receiving some voice then it's delayed even when both user cellphone who are calling are placed side by side.

I would obliged if sinch people would reach out and resolve this issue since I am almost finished with my project.

Comment: What kind of network are you on? Can you share a full log of the call flow (implement onLogMessage please=

Comment: how to do i it so that i get complete information of packets being sent and latency? inside this onLogMessage what should write please tell I am not getting anything on it.

Comment: It's nice that you responded and I am thankful for it. Please tell me how to do it so that i get complete information of packets being sent and latency? Inside this onLogMessage what should I write? please tell I am not getting anything on it.

Comment: public void onLogMessage(int level, String area, String message) {
   Log.d(message);
 }

Comment: @cjensen when I add "Log.d(message);" it says that it cannot resolve method 'd(java.lang.string)' though i tried this that's why I asked you how to do it because this isn't working

Comment: @cjensen It is working good enough when I am getting good connection.....But I have latency 30ms isn't it suppose to work super cool enough because I am facing issue like :

The volume on call established is very low even after setting volume control  "STREAM_VOICE_CALL" I mean Apps like whatsapp and IMO have voices like the person is sitting next if he/she actually is calling from the same place but when calling from different country the voice takes time to reach. But in this service I am testing from two cell phones and still in call voice delayed. I am a little worried about it.